# Efficiency of list.Reverse() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, processing-efficiency

Does anyone know how efficient .reverse() is in JS for reversing a list of objects?

I’m curious if there will be any meaningful performance loss for sorting a list (of say 100 objects) in ascending order and reversing it rather than just sorting the list in descending order.

**Edit:**
So I ran some tests of sorting an array descending and then ascending with reverse. The results are pretty interesting:
(Running in chromium)

- 1000 items in random order, descending normal sort, 10000 trials: 0.3681 ms
- 1000 items in random order, ascending sort then reverse, 10000 trials: 0.3651 ms
- 1000 items in ascending order, normal descending sort, 10000 trials: 0.0282 ms
- 1000 items in ascending order, ascending sort then reverse, 10000 trials: 0.0247 ms

Seems that .reverse() is not a very costly operation, especially when compared to sort.

Comment: Reverse will take O(n), trivially, so it would be better to sort it in the order you would like them to appear (descending, in your case)

Comment: @JClassic Can you elaborate on why it’s O(n)? Is it possible that JS uses a doubly-linked list behind the scenes for lists?

Comment: the time to reverse() an array of 100 elements is completely negligible except in the most sensitive applications.

Comment: Even if this is the case, it will still take O(n) to do (going through each node and swapping next and prev pointers). You pretty much cannot escape O(n) for reverse, unless you use a weird data structure

Comment: I think you are optimizing prematurely.

Comment: The only definitive answer is: Create a testcase, with your data on your device, run it a few thousand times and measure the time it takes.

Comment: Two operations is more than one. Just sort by descending.

Comment: @coffee_mug `.reverse()` isn't used that often. It wouldn't make sense to use doubly linked lists for all arrays in JS, if just some of them get reversed (interesting thought by the way)

Comment: @lux if you ignore all those abstractions going on under the hood, things are (too) easy.

Comment: @JonasWilms are you implying that sorting an unordered list (either asc or desc) and then reversing it, is more performant than just doing the single opposite sort operation?

Comment: @lux Yes, I think there are a lot of cases where that could happen. Take [1, 3, 4, 5, 2] for example.

Comment: @lux I agree that this question may be nitpicky but Occam’s razor isn’t universally applicable - especially in computer science. :)

Comment: @JonasWilms So you're solution would be to first 1) iterate over the array elements 2) perform logic to determine whether asc / desc would be most optimal 3) perform the sort operation 4) optionally reverse it, rather than 1) sort the way you need the items. On a list of 100 items? If there were ever a case for premature optimization/over-engineering, this would be it.

Comment: Thanks for the observations and thoughts, everyone. As someone stated, the only conclusive way to test this is to...test it. I’ll run time both sorts with varying number of elements and post the results. Wish I had enough points to upvote everyone.

Comment: @lux no, I just say we can't just say for sure. Maybe the data is already sorted somehow

Comment: So I ran some tests of sorting an array descending and then ascending with reverse. The results are pretty interesting:
_Running in chromium:_
- 1000 items in random order, descending normal sort, 10000  trials: 0.36810249999671213 ms  
- 1000 items in random order, ascending sort then reverse, 10000  trials: 0.36508599999770014 ms  
- 1000 items in ascending order, normal descending sort, 10000  trials: 0.02824799999525567 ms  
- 1000 items in ascending order, ascending sort then reverse, 10000  trials: 0.024710499998855086 ms

Answer (score 1):

The Ecma specification is vague about `Array#sort`, so the answer depends on the actual implementation, assuming we are talking about `V8` (Chrome, NodeJS), then we can say that for lists with `>10` elements the time complexity is `O(n log(n))` while the time complexity of `Array#reverse` is `O(n)`.

Given that, we can confidently say that it would be better to sort on a descending order directly since `sort + reverse` is evidently more expensive than just `sort`.

**sorting in a descendent order is equal to sorting in an ascending order.**

---

**UPDATE**: As stated by Jonas in the comment below, if you can notice a pattern on your list (e.g. the list is already asc-sorted), then probably you could just reverse it and save a `O(n log(n))` operation. Trying to understand the shape of your data is always the first step for performance optimisations.

Comment: Hmm. What if the array is already sorted ascending? Then sort + reverse could be faster ...

Comment: also note that a custom sort that uses a user-land callback executes much slower than a pure-C operation, like reverse().

Comment: @JonasWilms great point. dandavis, I wouldn't really focus on this because it is difficult to measure since it is really down to the interpreter. You would normally focus on the number of operations when talking about time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

[.reverse()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.reverse) works in O(n), which is evident from the linked spec. It will do a pairwise swap of elements.

To answer your question: `sort + reverse` is inevitably more expensive than `sort` alone, there is no shortcut made (as might be with a doubly linked list or some other data structure).